# Mock coordinates Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, mocking, location, android-location, locationmanager

In my app I am using Android Location Manager API and I have a requirement of identifying whether the location coordinates are from normal Location Manager or if they are from Fake(Mock) Location provider. I used `location.isFromMockProvider()`. Once I turn on the fake location providing app, isFromMockProvider() method returns me true. And after that it does not matter if I turn, fake location providing app, on or off isFromMockProvider() method always returns true.

I found that once FakeGPS app, once triggered, overrides the location manager coordinates and once I stop the FakeGPS app, the Location Manager does not start collecting correct coordinates.

Is there something I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disappointed with no response but I am glad that I got it working :)
Posting the resolution as it might help someone else.

Once the FakeGPS app starts mocking location, it stops my app's Location manager.
Now even if I stop the FakeGPS app mocking service, the location manager of my app won't trigger back.
I have to detect the event and restart the location manager of my app, after removing any test provider and clearing test locations.

Answer (score 0):

just resetting and removing test location should help

```
 String t = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
 locationManager.clearTestProviderEnabled(t);
 locationManager.clearTestProviderLocation(t);
 locationManager.clearTestProviderStatus(t);
 locationManager.removeTestProvider(t);
```